# Relevant method of uploading video

Tags: javascript, php, video, file-upload

I am dealing with a project that requires a video file to be uploaded and stored on my web hotel. I also need to store the file name string so that it is retrievable from a users profile.

I have some basic knowledge within PHP and JQuery/Javascript, what would be the general way you would approach this? Any quick tools/frameworks that can help?

Apogies for the generic question but I last coded some 10 years ago so my skill set is not up to date and do not want to start off on the wrong foot! Back in the days, I would have used the move_uploaded_file function and inserted the name into a MYSQL datbase but not sure if that is appropriate these days. Also, at that time the files were restricted to 2 MB which is way too small for videos.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

> I would have used the move_uploaded_file function and inserted the name into a MYSQL datbase but not sure if that is appropriate these days.

That's still about right. Here's the up-to-date tips you'll need:

- Use [PDO's](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). They're easier to migrate and manage. They're updated more than functions such as mysqli_query.
- Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), it's acceptable to NEVER concatenate strings while building SQL statements. Using prepared statements gives you 100% vulnerability against SQL injections
- Look into common pitfalls regarding user-uploaded files. For instances someone can upload a malicious script and execute it as php.